# asp.net page handlers

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

i want to add some httphandlers for aspx pages by code via a http module.

is that possible? if it is, how?

thanks your advance..

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? What is this module supposed to do and how it is related to the aspx page?

Comment: this module supposed to do create dynamic handlers for urls which defined in a custom section on web.config. on module initialization module should read the settings and create handlers what run the custom types.. :) sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

Inherit IHttpModule, override Application_BeginRequest perform your rewrite logic and rewrite the URL with:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) {
((HttpApplication)source).Context.RewritePath(...);
}
```

Then register it in web.config with:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="UrlRewriteHandler" type="namespace.UrlRewriteHandler,project"/>
</httpModules>
```

Hope that helps.